# DMBS: Union, intersection and difference with PhpMyAdmin and MySql opninons

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, passwords

I'm learning SQL and some friend adviced me to instal XAMPP as it's all preconfigured and ready to use. Well, I installed it and now I created 2 databases on which I exercise through PhpMyAdmin. That said, I'm trying to do 2 things:

a)Sets OperationsUnion, Intersect, Difference. The only available in PhpMyAdmin (and therefore MySql I guess, since I noticed that PhpMyAdmin is based on MySql) is UNION. INTERSECT AND DIFFERENCE keywords do not exist. How to do that then?

b)Using directly mysql.exe console. I try to use commands like USE databasename and so on, but it says "Access denied to user ''@'localhost to 'databasename'

I tried to put connect commands in all the flavours possible (connect user pass host db, connect user pass db, and all kind of combinations) but with no avail.

How to do that? Seems like Phpmyadmin set his own passwords for the databases. I put empty password and checked in the Phpmyadmin that those password were empty passwords. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: MySQL (unlike most modern DBMS) simply doesn't support `INTERSECT` or `EXCEPT`.

Comment: Why is that? Thanks to Explosion Pills's post I worked out that you do INTERSECT and EXCEPT with INNER AND OUTER JOINS.

Comment: Why is what? Do you mean: "*Why is MySQL missing so many standard SQL features?*" Well, I have no clue.

Comment: Yeah, I meant that, eheh. Thanks anyway. Would you mind taking a look at the question I'm asking about mysql.exe console usage? More details in the comments below.

Answer (score 0):

UNION keyword work perfectly fine on phpmyadmin. Phpmyadmin is just an interface for MySQL. Try to use "SQL" view in phpmyadmin to directly test your SQL queries.

If it comes to mysql.exe, try to connect using a user e.g. `root@localhost`. By default there should be no password for root.

Comment: I tried various commands like 

connect 'namedatabase' 'root@localhost' ' ' (empty password)

connect 'namedatabase' 'root' @' localhost' ' '

connect 'namedatabase' 'root' 'localhost' ' '

and many more. All give Access denied, cannot access the localhost blablablah and all that steaming BS.

What the hell? How is the right syntax?

Answer (score 0):

a) `UNION` is a MySQL keyword that is a union of two queries.  This is different than the *union*, *intersection*, and *difference* **concepts**, which are all achieved through `JOIN`s.  [This may help explain](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

b) As for your password, the username probably defaults to `root`, but it could be something else.  If you didn't set it up, the password is probably empty string.  Maybe try running `xampp\mysql\resetroot.bat`

Comment: re a) that's not entirely true. The SQL standard does know of `EXCEPT` (probably what the OP means with "difference") and `INTERSECT` (which *is* the intersection operator). It's not all "just" JOINs. But unlike most modern DBMS MySQL just doesn't support them.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but his question is about mysql

Comment: I know, but the OP "wants to learn SQL" so I thought he/she might be interested that this is simply a limitation of MySQL not of the language as such.

Comment: One last question, I was trying to access my Phpmyadmin databases from mysql.exe.
 I tried various commands like connect 'namedatabase' 'root@localhost' ' ' (empty password) connect 'namedatabase' 'root' @' localhost' ' ' connect 'namedatabase' 'root' 'localhost' ' ' and many more. All give Access denied, cannot access the localhost blablablah and all that steaming BS. What the hell? How is the right syntax?